# Timer in Raspberry Pi with micro seconds

Tags: raspbian, pi-4

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 and I use Python. Every 100us, I need to read ADC value and send it to a laptop via an Ethernet cable. I am looking for a solution about the timer with high accuracy, so that each ADC value is read correctly 100us, like timer interrupt on microcontroller. Thank for any suggestions!

Comment: What is a DC value?  How is it read?  Please edit your question to add this information.

Comment: My question has been edited by moderator or someone. I edited it again

Comment: You can google "raspberry pi timer" and get many results.

Comment: Do you have an ADC in mind?  How is it connected to the Pi?  How many bits?  What timing accuracy do you require, e.g, +/- 10 nanoseconds, +/- 10 microseconds?

Comment: My ADC has sample rate is 30kHz, joan.

Comment: Add clarifications to your question.  Unless you answer all the questions it is unlikely anyone can give useful help.

Comment: I have a module 24bit ADC in this [link](https://www.ebay.com/itm/194298993195?norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=21581-161791-616585-7&mkcid=2&itemid=194298993195&targetid=293946777986&device=c&mktype=pla&googleloc=1028580&poi=&campaignid=17488011556&mkgroupid=132913995730&rlsatarget=pla-293946777986&abcId=&merchantid=119648210&gclid=CjwKCAjwt7SWBhAnEiwAx8ZLaiBEIZIzTm9-r0AF3bBfOkCBDyanSLAF-JSzOMy8JkyG5VDP6znePhoCnc8QAvD_BwE), Data Output Rates to 30kSPS, connect with Rasp Pi via SPI. I need to read ADC value with period exactly 100 microseconds like when using timer interrupt in microcontroller.

Comment: *"a solution about the timer with high accuracy, so that each ADC value is read correctly 100us, like timer interrupt on microcontroller"* -> Then use a microcontroller, either attached to the Pi or via USB serial or whatever on your laptop.  A microprocessor controller by a contemporary multi-tasking OS is a great tool, but using it to, eg., make toast and coffee for you, or screw in a lightbulb, etc. is going to require some addition tool-parts or something completely different.  Another similar analogy: I would not use my smartphone for hammering in nails.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll have much luck with your approach.

Linux is not a real-time operating system. You can change the niceness of your process to -20, but even then there is no way of guaranteeing that some other activity won't block any userspace processes for multiple times of those 100μs. You may want to experiment with a custom-compiled Linux kernel with real-time extensions built in. But even with that your mileage will vary.

The problem, as posed by you, IMHO calls for either

- a kernel module, that does the sampling in kernel space, taking advantage of direct coupling to a timer interrupt, or
- a dedicated MCU between the Pi and the ADC, that performs the sampling and transmits the data by UART, for instance.

For both cases Python is inadequate(*), you'll need programming in C, and learn a bit about kernel programming or MCU programming. An MCU won't take more space for hardware if you can use the MCU's inbuilt ADC (usually 10bit, often 12bit, more rarely 14bit).

(*) I seem to remember seeing some MCU modules that can be programmed with Python. Likely, though, they also employ Linux to run the Python interpreter on top of.

Comment: Very few micro-controllers use Linux. Though there have been exceptions. However micropython and circuitpython do not depend on having Linux. And for reasons that you stated in your response, having Linux would be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how many samples you need to capture, if you just need a block of data that will fit into RAM, then you can acquire the data [using DMA](https://iosoft.blog/fast-data-capture-raspberry-pi/)

By chaining buffers it should be possible to stream data over the network continuously at 10 kHz.

Unfortunately Python won't be fast enough, you'll have to code in C, or any other fully-compiled language.